# Por que temos duas palavras para a cor "negra" e de onde elas vieram?

Tags: etimologia, origem, termos

Pode-se verificar paralelos da palavra "negro" em todos os idiomas de origem Latina que eu tenho conhecimento, negro (em espanhol), nero (em italiano), noir (em Francês), negre (em catalão), negru (em romeno), e por aí vai.

Entretanto temos também a palavra "preto" para definir a mesma cor, e esta não possui paralelo em nenhuma das nossas línguas irmãs. Minha pergunta então é, de onde vem a palavra "preto"? Porque, aparentemente, somos a única língua latina que desenvolveu 2 palavras para definir essa mesma cor?

Comment: Me desculpa pessoal mas ninguém vai dizer: Visto saia negra para trabalhar. né? Os usos são diferentes para essas duas palavras. O francés não tem essa palavra. charbon em francês é cinza em português, Schilive

Comment: @Lambie em Portugal a expressão que deste como exemplo poderia ser dita.

Comment: @bad_coder Acabo de procurar "vestir calça preta" e "vestir calça negra" em site:.pt O que deu na sua opinião? :)

Comment: @Lambie entre outros resultados [deu este na RTP](https://www.rtp.pt/noticias/cultura/teatro-do-vestido-revisita-aquilo-que-ouviamos-em-1980-90-para-falar-de-identidade_n1327614) também [deu este no JN](https://www.jn.pt/mundo/policia-de-hong-kong-dispersa-manifestantes-com-gas-lacrimogeneo-e-canhoes-de-agua-11302767.html), etc... Também há um fado muito conhecido chamado [Capas negras](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=capas+negras)

Comment: Eu concordo que *negro* e *preto* tendem a ter usos diferentes: *preto* é corriqueiro e neutro (pode-se dizer *vesti uma saia negra para ir trabalhar*, mas o normal é dizer-se *vesti uma saia preta*...) enquanto *negro* tende a ter um uso mais poético e afetivo ("teu cabelos [...] negros como a noite que não tem luar") ou metafórico (fazer a vida negra a alguém). Mas isto não tira mérito à pergunta.

Comment: @Jacinto Exato. A ceú negro e ameaçador, por exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Negro*** e os cognatos noutras línguas (*noir, nero*, etc.) vêm do latim [*niger*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Niger#Latin) (*nigrum* no acusativo, que é a fonte do português e castelhano), que já significava ’preto, escuro’ e, figuradamente, ’funesto, mau’ (ver [Etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=negro) e [CNTRL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/noir)).

Quanto a ***preto***, não era necessário que houvesse cognatos noutras línguas, mas até há [*prieto*](https://dle.rae.es/prieto?m=form) no castelhano; só que significa ’muito escuro ou quase preto’, não exatamente ’preto’.

A **origem de *preto*** não está isenta de controvérsia. O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) diz que é um derivado regressivo de ***apretar***, que é a forma original de ***apertar*** (daqui vem também *perto*, que no português medieval era *preto*; a forma *perto* está atestada só a partir do século XVI). Juan Corominas e José Pascual ([*Diccionario Crítico Etimológico Castellano e Hispánico*, 1984](https://archive.org/details/157203089-diccionario-critico-etimologico-castellano-a-ca-corominas-joan-pdf/page/n1/mode/2up)) dizem o mesmo do português *preto* e do castelhano *prieto*. Portanto o sentido original de *preto/prieto* seria ’apertado’. Aliás, o castelhano [*prieto*](https://dle.rae.es/prieto?m=form) continua a significar ’justo, apertado’ e ’duro ou denso’. Segundo o Houaiss e Corominas e Pascual, o sentido ’cor escura’ de *preto* viria de ’apertado’ no sentido ’denso, espesso’. [Corominas e Pascual (tomo I, p. 302-3](https://archive.org/details/157203089-diccionario-critico-etimologico-castellano-a-ca-corominas-joan-pdf/page/n1/mode/2up) explicam melhor (tradução minha):

> *Prieto* ’apertado’ […] É notável a aceção ’de cor escura’, ’negro’, que tomaram o castelhano antigo *prieto*⁷ e o português *preto*: procede da ideia de ’denso, espesso’ (sentido que [o castelhano] *apretado* tem em muitas passagens […]), que falando de névoa, poeira e análogos, equivale a ’escuro’

Agora, donde é que vem ***apretar*** é que já não há acordo. O Houaiss no verbete *preto* diz que vem da forma latina não atestada ****prettus***, que seria variante de ***pressus***, que é particípio passado de [*premĕre*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/premo#Latin); mas no verbete *apert*- diz que vem do latim tardio [***appectorāre***](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/appectoro#la), significando ’comprimir contra o peito’, derivado de *pectus*, ’peito’.

Ora *premĕre* significava ’premer, carregar’, e *pressus*, falando-se de cores, já significava ’deprimida, escura’ ([Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pressus) e [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=pressus&la=la&can=pressus0&d=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=pressus2&i=1#lexicon)). Podemos então perguntar porque é que *preto* não vem diretamente de **prettus*, em vez de via *apretar*. Na verdade, o [Aulete](https://aulete.com.br/preto) e o [Michaelis](https://aulete.com.br/preto) dispensam o *apretar* e simplesmente dizem que *preto* vem do latim **prettus* (mas não dizem que vem diretamente).

[Corominas e Pascual](https://archive.org/details/157203089-diccionario-critico-etimologico-castellano-a-ca-corominas-joan-pdf/page/n1/mode/2up) rejeitam a origem em *pressus*. Dizem que a forma ****prettus*** não é conhecida (o asterisco indica precisamente que a forma é conjetural) e que os únicos dois casos que eles conhecem de alternância entre -*ss*- e -*t*- no latim “são muito diferentes e têm explicações que não se poderiam aplicar a este *PRETTUS.”

A origem que eles defendem é: ***appectorāre → apetrar → apretar*** (em castelhano continua [*apretar*](https://dle.rae.es/apretar?m=form)). Eles notam que também do latim *pectus* pelas mesmas transformações vêm o castelhano [*pretil*](https://dle.rae.es/pretil?m=form) (’peitoril’) e [*pretal*](https://dle.rae.es/pretal?m=form), pelos visto agora mais comumente [*petral*](https://dle.rae.es/petral#CILBE3R) (’correia que passa no peito do cavalo’, [*peitoral*](https://aulete.com.br/peitoral)).

[Corominas e Pascual](https://archive.org/details/157203089-diccionario-critico-etimologico-castellano-a-ca-corominas-joan-pdf/page/n1/mode/2up) discutem e rejeitam ainda outras hipóteses, que também a mim me parecem muito especulativas. Podem ler o verbete completo (página e meia!) no link.

[Antenor Nascentes (*Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa*, 1955, p. 415)](https://archive.org/details/AntenorNascentesDicionaroEtimologicoDaLinguaPortuguesaTomoI/page/n453/mode/2up?view=theater&q=%22Jo%C3%A3o%20Ribeiro%20Seleta%22) apresenta ainda outras hipóteses. Diz que houve quem sugerisse origem no grego *pyraithés*, ’ardente, queimado pelo fogo’, e que o filólogo João Ribeiro propôs origem no latim *pletu*, ’cheio’, por uma associação em que “*branco* passou a designar vazio (*em branco*) e *preto* designava *cheio*”. Contra esta hipótese foi observado que *pletu* nunca daria *prieto* em castelhano, e que o latim *plere* (donde derivaria *pletu*) não é conhecido por si só; apenas com elemento compositivo de outros verbos, como *implere*, que nos deu *encher*, *complere*, que nos deu *cumprir*, etc.