# Qual a diferença entre negro ou preto aplicado a uma pessoa?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, significado-em-contexto

Qual a diferença entre negro ou preto aplicado a uma pessoa ?

Comment: Depende: em Portugal, Mozambique, Angola, Cabo Verde, os Azores, São Tomé e Principle, Timor-Leste, Macau ou o Brasil? Assunto complicado, né? :)

Comment: @Lambie Sem dúvida aspectos importantes vão depender do país - assim como também variam dentro do Brasil.

Comment: Mulato em Brazil, não?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Em poucas palavras

É complicado.

Por conta do racismo, esta pergunta toca em um tema polêmico, carregado politicamente e em fluxo — de forma que não existe uma maneira amplamente aceita de se utilizar essas palavras quando aplicadas a pessoas. Eu sugeriria:

- evitar esses termos (assim como "mestiço", "mulato", "caboclo", etc.), excetuando-se para autodeterminação;
- para descrever pessoas, afirmações factuais como "de pele escura" são preferíveis;
- em conteúdo dissertativo, explicitar as definições usadas para os termos.

---

##### Explicando

O termo "negro", por exemplo, pode indicar cor de pele, mas também etnia, e é (potencialmente) mais ofensivo que "preto", ou menos, ou tanto quanto:

> - Indivíduo de pele não-branca (*pode ser considerado ofensivo*). [[dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/negro/)]
> - Indivíduo de pele escura; PRETO [[aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/negro)]
> - Indivíduo de etnia negra. [[Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/negro/)]

E similarmente para "preto":

> - Pejorativo. Indivíduo de pele escura. [[aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/preto)]
> - Algo ou alguém cuja cor da pele é negra. [[dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/preto/)]
> - Indivíduo da raça negra.  [[Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/preto/)]

Quando se autoidentificam, a maioria das pessoas no Brasil se coloca em mais de uma categoria, refletindo as diferentes acepções e percepções individuais dos termos:

[image: tabela do IBGE com proporção de pessoas por autoidentificação de cor ou raça]
<sub>Fonte: *Características étnico-raciais da população: classificações e identidades*, IBGE, 2013, [ISBN 9788524042447](https://biblioteca.ibge.gov.br/index.php/biblioteca-catalogo?view=detalhes&id=284235), pg. 35.</sub>

Aqui, "negro" aparece com maior frequência que "preto", o que pode indicar um fato demográfico, ou preferência pelo termo, ou ainda adoção da acepção "etnia", etc.

Outro resultado do Censo, que enfatiza a sutileza e complexidade do tema cor, é a comparação da autodeclaração aberta (sem lista de alternativas) com a fechada:

[image: comparação da autodeclaração aberta (sem lista de alternativas) com a fechada (com lista)]
<sub>Fonte: *Características étnico-raciais da população: classificações e identidades*, IBGE, 2013, [ISBN 9788524042447](https://biblioteca.ibge.gov.br/index.php/biblioteca-catalogo?view=detalhes&id=284235), pg 66.</sub>

A tabela evidencia a grande sobreposição que existe entre os termos, e também sugere uma considerável fluidez na sua aplicação. Nota-se, por exemplo, que dentre as pessoas que espontaneamente se declararam negras, metade assinala a alternativa "preto" quando oferecida (e que 1/4 se declara indígena e 1/8, branco); enquanto dentre aqueles que espontaneamente se declaram pretos, frações semelhantes (~80%) escolhem a alternativa "preto" e/ou "negro" (e 14%, "branco").

Em vista disso, o que significa uma pessoa ser "negra", ou "preta"? Não há resposta simples.

Tangencialmente relacionado, já há uma pergunta sobre a [etimologia](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/9273/2764) destes termos.

Comment: Resposta excelente por incluir o quadro com os diferentes termos.

Comment: @bad_coder As pessoas, quando pedidas para se autoidentificar com relação a raça/cor/etnia - sem o auxílio de uma lista - usam mais de 140 termos diferentes ("moreno" é uma opção popular, mas vários se declaram da raça "brasileira" ou "italiana"). Dei outra olhada na publicação do IBGE e esbarrei em dados mais interessantes ainda, que incluí agora na resposta.

Comment: O Brasil está precisando de uma reforma. :) Credo. Sempre achei que essa tabela reflete a confusão sobre esse assunto no Brasil. O mundo lusophono vai bem além do Brasil...:)

Comment: @Lambie Sim, minha resposta sem dúvida se foca no Brasil.